# Problem in converting string format into date in Athena

Tags: sql

Request your help as have been trying to solve this but not able to.

I have a column in athena which is string . I want to convert that column into timestamp in athena.

I have used the query:

```
select date_parse(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') from wqmparquetformat ;
```

But i am getting errors: 
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "1589832352" is malformed at "832352"

I have tried all the combination of Presto in timestamp format.

When i run the below query :

```
select to_iso8601(from_unixtime(1589832352));
```

I receive the below output:

```
2020-05-18T20:05:52.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

The date_parse() function expects (string, format) as parameters and returns timestamp. So you need to pass your string as shown below :

```
select date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(1589832352)),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```

which gave me below output

```
2020-05-18 20:05:52.000
```

You need to pass the column name contains the value 1589832352 in your case

```
select date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(timestamp)),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```

In your case you should cast timestamp as double for it to work as shown below:

```
select date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(cast(timestamp as double))),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```

To test run below query which works fine.

```
select date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(cast('1589832352' as double))),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```

Comment: I need to do it on column name table timestamp not on a single entry

Comment: I see that you mentioned this value in your question and I thought this will be the format for timestamp you have in your data. You just need to replace the entry with timestamp in your query. I have updated the answer

Comment: Hi - When i run the above command : select date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(timestamp)),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') from wqmparquetformat  i get the error:SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:30: Unexpected parameters (varchar) for function from_unixtime. Expected: from_unixtime(double) , from_unixtime(double, bigint, bigint) , from_unixtime(double, varchar(x))

Comment: Can you confirm your timestamp column data type?

Comment: Hi Prabhakar - Data type for timestamp is in string

Comment: Hi @Prabhakar - Can you please reply. I am still stuck.

Comment: Can you try casting the data type as double. I have updated my answer with cast.

Answer (score 0):

For me, date_format works great in AWS Athena:

`SELECT date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(datetime), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i') AS myDateTime FROM <table>;`

OR

`select date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') from wqmparquetformat ;`